# can you help me understand about fopen("contact.dll", "r");

Tags: c, dll, directory, phone-number

I'm trying to implement phonebook in C using data structure.
I found some source code and I'm trying to understand this code but there is really big problem I've never seen. It is dll. I googled about dll but there is nothing related about this. I know the meaning and purpose of dll, but why do we use `fopen contact.dll` ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<dos.h>
struct contact
{
    long phone;
    char name[20],add[20],email[30];
} list;
char query[20],name[20];
FILE *fp, *ft;
int i,n,ch,l,found;
int main()
{
main:
    system("cls");    /* ************Main menu ***********************  */
    printf("\n\t **** Welcome to Contact Management System ****");  
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tMAIN MENU\n\t\t=====================\n\t\t[1] Add a new Contact\n\t\t[2] List all Contacts\n\t\t[3] Search for contact\n\t\t[4] Edit a Contact\n\t\t[5] Delete a Contact\n\t\t[0] Exit\n\t\t=====================\n\t\t");
    printf("Enter the choice:");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch)
    {
    case 0:
        printf("\n\n\t\tAre you sure you want to exit?");
        break;
        /* *********************Add new contacts************  */
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        fp=fopen("contact.dll","a");
        for (;;)
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("To exit enter blank space in the name input\nName (Use identical):");
            scanf("%[^\n]",&list.name);
            if(stricmp(list.name,"")==0 || stricmp(list.name," ")==0)
                break;
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("phone:");
            scanf("%ld",&list.phone);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("address:");
            scanf("%[^\n]",&list.add);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("email address:");
            gets(list.email);
            printf("\n");
            fwrite(&list,sizeof(list),1,fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        break;
        /* *********************list of contacts*************************  */
    case 2:
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\t\t================================\n\t\t\tLIST OF CONTACTS\n\t\t================================\n\nName\t\tphone No\t    Address\t\tE-mail ad.\n=================================================================\n\n");
        for(i=97; i<=122; i=i+1)  
        {
            fp=fopen("contact.dll","r");
            fflush(stdin);
            found=0;
            while(fread(&list,sizeof(list),1,fp)==1)
            {
                if(list.name[0]==i || list.name[0]==i-32)
                {
                    printf("\nName\t: %s\nphone\t: %ld\nAddress\t: %s\nEmail\t: %s\n",list.name,
                           list.phone,list.add,list.email);
                    found++;
                }
            }
            if(found!=0)
            {
              printf("=========================================================== [%c]-(%d)\n\n",i-32,found);
                getch();
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
        break;
        /* *******************search contacts**********************  */
    case 3:
        system("cls");
        do
        {
            found=0;
            printf("\n\n\t..::CONTACT SEARCH\n\t===========================\n\t..::Name of contact to search: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%[^\n]",&query);
            l=strlen(query);
            fp=fopen("contact.dll","r");
            system("cls");
            printf("\n\n..::Search result for '%s' \n===================================================\n",query);
            while(fread(&list,sizeof(list),1,fp)==1)
            {
                for(i=0; i<=l; i++)
                    name[i]=list.name[i];
                name[l]='\0';
                if(stricmp(name,query)==0)
                {
                    printf("\n..::Name\t: %s\n..::phone\t: %ld\n..::Address\t: %s\n..::Email\t: %s\n",list.name,list.phone,list.add,list.email);
                    found++;
                    if (found%4==0)
                    {
                        printf("..::Press any key to continue...");
                        getch();
                    }
                }
            }
            if(found==0)
                printf("\n..::No match found!");
            else
                printf("\n..::%d match(s) found!",found);
            fclose(fp);
            printf("\n ..::Try again?\n\n\t[1] Yes\t\t[0] No\n\t");
            scanf("%d",&ch);
        }
        while(ch==1);
        break;
        /* *********************edit contacts************************/
    case 4:
        system("cls");
        fp=fopen("contact.dll","r");
        ft=fopen("temp.dat","w");
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("..::Edit contact\n===============================\n\n\t..::Enter the name of contact to edit:");
        scanf("%[^\n]",name);
        while(fread(&list,sizeof(list),1,fp)==1)
        {
            if(stricmp(name,list.name)!=0)
                fwrite(&list,sizeof(list),1,ft);

        }
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n\n..::Editing '%s'\n\n",name);
        printf("..::Name(Use identical):");
        scanf("%[^\n]",&list.name);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("..::phone:");
        scanf("%ld",&list.phone);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("..::address:");
        scanf("%[^\n]",&list.add);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("..::email address:");
        gets(list.email);
        printf("\n");
        fwrite(&list,sizeof(list),1,ft);
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(ft);
        remove("contact.dll");
        rename("temp.dat","contact.dll");
        break;
        /* ********************delete contacts**********************/
    case 5:
        system("cls");
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n\n\t..::DELETE A CONTACT\n\t===============================\n\t..::Enter the name of contact to delete:");
        scanf("%[^\n]",&name);
        fp=fopen("contact.dll","r");
        ft=fopen("temp.dat","w");
        while(fread(&list,sizeof(list),1,fp)!=0)
            if (stricmp(name,list.name)!=0)
                fwrite(&list,sizeof(list),1,ft);
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(ft);
        remove("contact.dll");
        rename("temp.dat","contact.dll");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid choice");
        break;
    }
    printf("\n\n\n..::Enter the Choice:\n\n\t[1] Main Menu\t\t[0] Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch (ch)
    {
    case 1:
        goto main;
    case 0:
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid choice");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: in `for(i=97; i<=122; i=i+1)` it would be clearer if you used `for(i='w'; i<='z'; i++) ` if that's what you really meant. BTW `fflush()` an input stream is not implemented on all systems.

Comment: TL;DR, but:1) `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour, 2) Avoid `goto` where it does not add to code-readability (as in your code). 3) Use functions. 4) Always check the result of functions which can encounter an error. 5) `while(ch==1);`?

Comment: thank you guys :) very helpful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the way the file is used, contact.dll is not an actual Windows DLL, but a datafile that this application used to store phonebook entries.

The various cases add, remove, update, and retrieve `list` entries from the file.  The name given to the file is misleading.

Comment: oh i see ...
so you mean is it similar with contact.txt or contact.dat ?
and then can we use dll as just file to store data? isnt it library file ? 
i heard that many program can share that

Comment: @aloefreshman What I means is that calling the file "contact.dll" was not a good choice for the filename because it is not a Dynamic Link Library.  It should have been called "contact.dat" or phonebook.dat" or something similar.

Comment: @aloefreshman Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.